# Mapping function restrictions?

Tags: java, mapping

I am mapping a time table in the format of: `Map<Route, List<Service>> read(String fileName)`

Can I have multiple Lists on the same key? For example:

```
timeTable.put(route66,["32","55","33","12","15"]);
timeTable.put(route66,["66","5","33","43","77"]);
timeTable.put(route66,["12","56","33","67","35"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the [contract for `Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) clearly states:

> A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

In addition, your code isn't close to valid Java, as arrays aren't `List`s, and those are strings, not whatever `Service` might be.

You might, however, be interested in Guava's [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), which is essentially a map from keys to a collection of values.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, Map keys are unique. In your case, the last value will override the others.
What you may want to do is have a map like `Map<Route, List<String[]>>`. It means that any entry you have will contain a list of String arrays

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. But you may keep for the same key a List of your lists:

```
Map<Route, List<List<Service>>>
```